# How to store rendered output of a Google cached webpage?

Tags: linux, caching, lynx

I'm trying to get the output of a Google cached webpage:

`lynx -dump https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qh7F3C-sax0J:https://news.google.ca/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca > file`

This produces an empty file. I've noticed that lynx makes multiple threads to process the webpage. But is there any way to produce the output in a file?

Comment: Try enclosing the url in quotes. It is rather complicated and confuses lynx.

Comment: Oh that worked! Great!